# Reduce the number of elements I hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

The level 3 menu is broken in 2 parts if there are more than 10 items. The issue is with hovering over the newly created list.

At this moment I have 3 functions that apply the shown-sub class. I want to reduce it to only one. It should work when hovering over cotton and both ul lists.

```js
 !function(){
 $("#nav ul.level0 ul.level1").each(function(){
  var menuLength = $(this).find("li.level2").length;
  if (menuLength > 10){
   var detachedElements = $(this).find("li.level2").slice(10);
   detachedElements.detach();
   $(this).parent().append("<ul class='level1 second-menu'></ul>");
   detachedElements.appendTo($(this).siblings(".second-menu"));
  }
  $(this).siblings("a").hover(
   function(){
    $(this).siblings(".second-menu").addClass("shown-sub");
   }, 
   function(){
    $(this).siblings(".second-menu").removeClass("shown-sub");
   }
  );
  $(this).children(".level2").hover(
   function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings(".second-menu").addClass("shown-sub");
   }, 
   function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings(".second-menu").removeClass("shown-sub");
   }
  );
  $(this).siblings(".second-menu").children(".level2").hover(
   function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("shown-sub");
   }, 
   function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("shown-sub");
   }
  );
 })
 }();
```

```css
.second-menu{
  color:red;  
}
.shown-sub{
 color:blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="level0 nav-2 active level-top parent">
      <a class="level-top" href="http://higgs.limebuild.net/fabrics.html">
        <span>link text</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="level0">
        <li class="level1 nav-2-1 first active parent">
          <a class="" href="http://higgs.limebuild.net/fabrics/cotton.html">
            <span>Cotton</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="level1">
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-1 first">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-2">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-3">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-4">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-5">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-6">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-7">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-8">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-9">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-10">has to be black</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-11">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-12">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-13">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-14">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-15">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-16">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-17">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-18">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-19">has to be blue on hover</li>
            <li class="level2 nav-2-1-20 last">has to be blue on hover</li>
           </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particularly with your example, I'm not sure if is the kind of functionality what you want, but you can use pure html + css for get a similar approach, using `:hover` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cywb3yg/4/

If doesn't work for you, and want to keep your code, I refactored a couple of things.

I think you are add/remove the same class. I extracted in a generic function, and apply independently to each element.

```
    function setToggles($mainElement, $subElement) {

    var hoverIn = function () {
       $subElement.addClass("shown-sub");
    };

    var hoverOut = function () {
       $subElement.removeClass("shown-sub");
    };       

    $mainElement.hover(hoverIn,hoverOut);
}
```

Also I extract a couple of variables with the convention `$variable` for jQuery elements.

Particularly in this example you are using a lot of jQuery selectors,that can be re-use extracting in a variables. (that was the way what i found the extract code)

Also you chain a lot of jQuery calls, Is not bad, but in excess is easy lose `who` is receive the last message.And can be a mess for human-reading.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cywb3yg/3/